# How to Implement Funds that Different Grants Belong to?

Tags: civicontribute, custom-fields, civigrant

How would I go about implementing funds that different grants belong to? There would be annual funding rounds based on them. CiviGrant by itself doesn't provide this functionality.

Two ways to implement this come to mind. One (though very limited way) would be through custom fields, the other by creating a whole new entity tied to grants (which would require some coding). Maybe there is a way use campaigns as funds, but how would I go about connecting campaigns to grants?
Is there some work already done on this? How have you dealt with this kind of thing?

Comment: Could you expand a bit on the behaviour you want around funds?  Is this about grants that you make or receive?  Trying to get a better picture of what you need.

Comment: My question is about the grants the organization makes. The functionality will involve keeping records of grants in each fund and enabling users to browse previous grants by funds (displaying info made in the previous rounds of each fund etc.). I started working on small module that creates two new tables Fund and FundGrant. But I am not quite sure if that is the right path.